# customErrors mode=“Off” in web.config but still Server Error in ‘/’ Application

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I deployed an asp.net website to a shared server.....

I got the error

`Server Error in '/' Application.`

**Runtime Error**

`Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.`

Here is my page http://static3.nextgenits.com/Forms/Homepage.aspx

What am i missing ?... Any suggestion...

Comment: I get almost same error.This is my question.Thanks 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301964/share-hosting-customerrors-mode-off-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application's web.config is not configured to show the error messages remotely. You will have to edit your web.config and un-comment the customErrors section. Also make sure you set it to RemoteOnly . Once you do this you will see the actual error on the screen and then you can correct it accordingly. Here is the web.config section to be used:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
```

Comment: I've set the custom errors section as stated above but still can't see the errors. Debug is set to `true`. IIS is version 5.1 running on windows XP. This is a local machine I'm trying to access through local network.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to `debug="true"` and you will see the error. Or browse it from the local machine if thats possible. I would also recommend you use something like [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to log errors in your application. Then you will always be able to see the error when you have your custom error pages set.

The reason you get the message is because you have some other error that asp.net doesn't want to display in release mode as it might contain sensitive information that you don't want the end use to see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a typo in your web.config preventing asp.net to eval. customErrors section.

**EDIT:**
Bit more clear. If there is an error in the web.config (it's an XML File) then ASP.NET isn't able to parse that file. This is an error. As asp.net can't parse the web.config it ignores any settings.